# Computation of the solution of a particular differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $g(x)=\frac {dx}{dt}$, we want to solve 
$$ 
\frac {\partial n(x,t)}{\partial t}+ 
\frac {\partial (n(x,t)g(x))}{\partial x}=-\mu(x)n(x,t). 
$$
where we can assume all the regularity properties on the functions $g$ and  $\mu$, we search for $n(x,t)>0$ and $x \in \mathbb R$, $t \in (0,\infty)$.
Is it true that 
$$ 
\frac {\partial n(x,t)}{\partial t}+ 
\frac {\partial n(x,t)}{\partial x}g(x)=-\mu(x)n(x,t)- \frac {\partial g(x)}{\partial x}n(x,t) 
$$
hence by the definition of $g$ we have that
$$ 
\frac {dn(x,t)}{dt} =-\mu(x)n(x,t)- \frac {\partial g(x)}{\partial x}n(x,t) 
$$
Hence,  if $n_0(x)= n(0,x)$,
$n(x,t)=n_0(x) \exp(-t (\mu(x)+\frac {\partial g(x)}{\partial x}))$
?

If not why is it not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean that $g$ is given, and you are trying to 
analyze the PDE by looking at the behavior of $n$ along
a curve $x(t)$ that satisfies $x'(t) = g(x(t))$.

With that understanding, your last equation ought to be written
$$
 \frac{d}{dt}(n(x(t),t)) = -(\mu(x(t))+g'(x(t)))n(x(t),t).
$$
But the solutions of the ODE $y'(t) = b(t)y(t)$ are of the 
form
$$
        y(t) = y(0)\exp(\int_0^t b(s)ds).
$$
So if you can find $x(t)$ and do the integral, the result will
give $n$ along the curve.